# How do I pass enum from parent to child component?

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to pass enum from parent to child component.

I have this enum:

```
export enum Status {
  A = 'A',
  B = 'B',
  C = 'C'
}
```

and here is componenmt:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-enum-selection',
  templateUrl: './enum-selection.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./enum-selection.component.scss']
})
export class EnumSelectionComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() enum: Object;
  enumKeys=[];

  constructor() { 
    this.enumKeys=Object.keys(this.enum);  
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

Here how I use child component in parent component:

```
<app-enum-selection [enum]="Status"></app-enum-selection>
```

As you can see above I pass enum Status to the component but enum value is always null.

Why Status is not passed to the component?
How do I pass enum from parent to child component?

Comment: Why are you trying to pass the entire enum into the child component and not importing the enum directly into the child?

Comment: @BrianSmith because I want to create drop-box from enums items and drop-box I try to do it generic, so it will create dropbox from different enum types.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign the Enum to an attributte of the parent component. Ex:

> public myStatus = Status;

And then pass it on the input for the child component:

> <app-enum-selection [enum]="myStatus">

Answer (score 1):

An enum is a type, not a variable.  You don't pass a type, you pass a variable of that type.  So instead of [enum]="Status" (which is a type), you would do something like this:

```js
// note: the enum should be in its own file, so you can import it into both the parent and child components. 

export enum Status {
  A = 'A',
  B = 'B',
  C = 'C'
}

// in parent component
public myStatus: Status = Status.A;
```

Then in your parent HTML:

```html
<app-enum-selection [statusValue]="myStatus"></app-enum-selection>
```

The child component gets changed thusly:

```js
import { Status } from './wherever-the-file-lives';

@Input()
public statusValue: Status;
```

Answer (score -1):

you dont need to pass enum if you want use it in child component
you can directly use enum in child component by importing it

in child ts:

```
import { Status } from 'path-to-enum-file.ts';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-enum-selection',
  templateUrl: './enum-selection.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./enum-selection.component.scss']
})
export class EnumSelectionComponent implements OnInit {
  enumKeys=[];

  constructor() { 
    this.enumKeys=Object.keys(Status);  
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

if you want to use it in child HTML do this in ts:

```
Status = Status;
```